# Trouble converting to signed 16 bit array

Tags: swift, pointers, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am retrieving data from a sensor via BLE.
I am converting the bytes from NSData to signed 16 bit array of integers.  However I am getting an error saying

```
Argument type '[Int16]' does not conform to expected type '_Pointer'
```

Is there a better way ? Any help is appreciated.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

    if characteristic.uuid == tempUUID {

        let dataBytes = characteristic.value
        let dataCount = dataBytes?.count

        var dataArray = [Int16](repeating: 0, count: dataCount!)
        dataBytes.getBytes(dataArray, length:dataCount! * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)

        let finalAnswer = Double(dataArray[1])/128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can copy the data into an integer array (Swift 3/4):

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    var dataArray = [Int16](repeating: 0, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride)
    dataArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
        _ = data.copyBytes(to: $0)
    }
    let finalAnswer = Double(dataArray[1])/128
}
```

If you need only a single value then you can access that without
creating an array:

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    let i16value = data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
        ptr[1]
    }
    let finalAnswer = Double(i16value)/128
}
```

Another option:

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    let i16value = data.subdata(in: 2..<4).withUnsafeBytes {
        UnsafeRawPointer($0).load(as: Int16.self)
    }
    let finalAnswer = Double(i16value)/128
}
```